# Using a JAXB XmlAdapter to adapt an entire list without a wrapper element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, xmladapter

I'm trying to use an `XmlAdapter` to unmarshal `XML` into a custom collection type (that intentionally does not implement the `Collection` interface due to a conflicting restriction imposed by another use of the class, which unfortunately fails if the class contains any collections). The difficulty is that the `XML` nodes that will be placed into the collection are not wrapped in a wrapper element.

Here's what my `XML` essentially looks like:

```
<xml>
  <foo></foo>
  <bar>1</bar>
  <bar>2</bar>
</xml>
```

I can make `JAXB` unmarshall this to the following `POJO`:

```
class Naive {
  Foo foo;
  List<Bar> bar;
}
```

However, what I want to do is the following:

```
class Bars {
  // There will be a fixed number of these, known in advance
  Bar bar1;
  Bar bar2; 
}

class BarsAdapter extends XmlAdapter<ArrayList<Bar>, Bars> {
  ...
}

class Custom {
  Foo foo;
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BarsAdapter.class)  // won't work
  Bars bar;
}
```

As you can see, I wrote an `XmlAdapter` that wants to adapt the entire list, not the individual elements, but it never gets invoked for unmarshalling. (It does get invoked for marshalling.)

If my `XML` contained a wrapper around the `<bar>` elements, then I know how to solve this:

```
<xml>
  <foo></foo>
  <wrapper>
    <bar>1</bar>
    <bar>2</bar>
  </wrapper>
</xml>
```

because then I could annotate the `bars` field with `@XmlElement(id="wrapper")` and the adapter would get correctly called. However, the `XML` schema comes from an `RFC` and is entirely unchangeable, so I am stuck as to how to proceed. Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: have you tried using a setter?

Comment: What would that look like?

Comment: something like `@XmlValue public void setBar(List<Bar> bars){this.Bars = new Bars(bar.get(0),bar.get(1));}`